# Reading writing from offset

Tags: c++, c, file-io

```
bool CReadWrite::write(unsigned long long offset, void* pvsrc, unsigned long long nbytes)
{   int WriteResult;

    pFile = fopen("D:\\myfile.bin","wb");

    if (!pFile){   
        puts("Can't open file"); 
        return false;
    }

    //offset = fseek(pFile,offset,

    WriteResult = fwrite (pvsrc, 1, nbytes, pFile);

    if (WriteResult == nbytes){   
        puts("Wrote to file");
        fclose(pFile);
        return true;
    }
    else{   
        puts("Unable to write to File."); 
        fclose(pFile);
        return false;
    }   
}
```

This is my class function so far. I'm basically opening a file, checking to see if it did indeed open if not get out. Writes the file, checks to see if the file see if the file was indeed written to returns true. else return false. As you can tell by my parameters, I'm looking to create an offset where I can give a particular offset i.e. 10, and start from 10 and then from there write. I know for sure I need to use fseek but I can't assume that I'm at the beginning of the file or anywhere in the file. Im pretty sure i need to use SEEK_SET but I may be wrong. Any thoughts on implemented the above desires? Thanks.

Comment: If it's C++ code, why aren't you using `fstream`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `fopen` without the append setting (as you are, "wb" creates an empty file), you can assume you're at the beginning.

Regardless, `SEEK_SET` sets the position to the given offset from the beginning.

If the file doesn't have the offset that you want to seek to (as it is in your case), then the question is what are you required to do? If just pad - then write `offset` padding bytes, and then your content, otherwise maybe you wanted to use "a" and not "w". "w" truncates the existing content of the file, while "a" opens for append and sets position to the end of the existing content.

More details [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen).

Comment: I would like the option to say if i already have 10 bytes in the file, to go to offset 7 and write from there. Or starting from any offset I give it to be able to write from there on nbytes.

Comment: Also, I think i need to use ftell as well since I'm interested in possibly writing somewhere in the file to calculate the ammount of bytes in the file itself

Comment: @Questioneer if you already have data in the file - don't open it with "w", but use "a" instead, and then use `fseek`. Getting info about the size of the file can be done with `fstat`. You're asking a bunch of rather unrelated questions, why not just reading the `stdio` reference?

Comment: I may or may not have data already in the file. Sorry for being so vague :/